# How to print a .CSV file completely in java output console?

Tags: java, eclipse, csv

I am trying to read a .CSV file which consists of postal codes and their addresses across a country. Whenever I try to read the file, the print console just shows a part of the file and not the whole file. What should I do to print the whole file to the console.

I am working on eclipse and I have tried both CSVreader(openCSV library) and scanner inputStream but they show different results when complied each time.

```
public class Database
{

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {

      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));

      List<String[]> allRows = reader.readAll();

      for(String[] row : allRows){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
     }
   }
}
```

Expected:

[Chakragaon ,S.O,744112]

[Chatham ,S.O,744102]

[Delanipur, S.O,744102]

[Marine Jetty, S.O,744101]

[Minnie Bay, S.O,744103]

[N.S.Building,S.O,744101]

Actual:

[Minnie Bay, S.O,744103]

[N.S.Building,S.O,744101]

The file consists of 100,000+ rows.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be a printing issue. First, you should check that you actually read more than 2 rows. For that, I recommend using a debugger (sounds like you're using eclipse based on your tag) and place a breakpoint at after reading the rows. Get the size...

The bottom line is if the behavior of a program diverges from what you were expecting, there is not better solution than using your debugger, trace through it line by line, look at the variables in the variables view and see where things didn't go the way you thought they should have.

Comment: I used the debugger and it seems that it is printing all the values but not in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into this issue because of the `reader.readAll()` - the reader has a safety catch to prevent you overflowing your memory by reading in massive files. Instead, only read one row at a time, print, then move on to the next row:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("data.csv"));

for(String[] row : reader) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

The for loop syntax recognizes `CSVReader` as an `Iterable<String[]>` so it can loop over the lines automatically.

Comment: I tried this method before and it didn't work. I debugged the code and saw that it prints line by line.

Comment: If you'd like help, please explain what "didn't work" means :)

Comment: Printing the whole file itself, I believe my approach was wrong. File with 100,000 records can't be displayed on the console.